# Embedding second font in PrivateFontCollection c#

Tags: c#, fonts, embed

with this code i'm able to embed a specific font in a c# winform application:

```html
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Text;


namespace XCopyPro
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //codice per utilizzare il font distribuito
            LoadFont();
            lbl_mode.Font = new Font(private_fonts.Families[0], 42);
            lbl_mode.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
        }

        // carichiamo il font distribuito in memoria
        PrivateFontCollection private_fonts = new PrivateFontCollection();
        private void LoadFont()
        {
            // specify embedded resource name
            string resource = "XCopyPro.Resources.jd_lcd_rounded.ttf";
            // receive resource stream
            Stream fontStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
            // create an unsafe memory block for the font data
            System.IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)fontStream.Length);
            // create a buffer to read in to
            byte[] fontdata = new byte[fontStream.Length];
            // read the font data from the resource
            fontStream.Read(fontdata, 0, (int)fontStream.Length);
            // copy the bytes to the unsafe memory block
            Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, data, (int)fontStream.Length);
            // pass the font to the font collection
            private_fonts.AddMemoryFont(data, (int)fontStream.Length);
            // close the resource stream
            fontStream.Close();
            // free the unsafe memory
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data);
        }

    }
}
```

Now i would like add a second Font to my collection and use it to another object, but if it's possible i would like to re-use the same variables to have a better looking code... There is a way?

EDIT: I found the solution myself:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Text;


namespace XCopyPro
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //codice per utilizzare il font distribuito
            LoadFont();
            lbl_mode.Font = new Font(private_fonts.Families[1], 42);
            lbl_mode.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
            lbl_desc_1.Font = new Font(private_fonts.Families[0], 14);
            lbl_desc_1.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
            lbl_desc_2.Font = new Font(private_fonts.Families[0], 14);
            lbl_desc_2.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
            lbl_status.Font = new Font(private_fonts.Families[1], 29);
            lbl_status.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
        }

        // carichiamo il font distribuito in memoria
        PrivateFontCollection private_fonts = new PrivateFontCollection();
        private void LoadFont()
        {
            // specify embedded resource name
            string resource = "XCopyPro.Resources.jd_lcd_rounded.ttf";
            // receive resource stream
            Stream fontStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
            // create an unsafe memory block for the font data
            System.IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)fontStream.Length);
            // create a buffer to read in to
            byte[] fontdata = new byte[fontStream.Length];
            // read the font data from the resource
            fontStream.Read(fontdata, 0, (int)fontStream.Length);
            // copy the bytes to the unsafe memory block
            Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, data, (int)fontStream.Length);
            // pass the font to the font collection
            private_fonts.AddMemoryFont(data, (int)fontStream.Length);
            // close the resource stream
            fontStream.Close();
            // free the unsafe memory
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data);
            // proviamo con il secondo font
            // specify embedded resource name
            resource = "XCopyPro.Resources.Final_Frontier.ttf";
            // receive resource stream
            fontStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
            // create an unsafe memory block for the font data
            data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)fontStream.Length);
            // create a buffer to read in to
            fontdata = new byte[fontStream.Length];
            // read the font data from the resource
            fontStream.Read(fontdata, 0, (int)fontStream.Length);
            // copy the bytes to the unsafe memory block
            Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, data, (int)fontStream.Length);
            // pass the font to the font collection
            private_fonts.AddMemoryFont(data, (int)fontStream.Length);
            // close the resource stream
            fontStream.Close();
            // free the unsafe memory
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider posting a solution as an answer to the question and then accepting it.

Comment: as per @Spo1ler's comment, don't edit your post with the answer, write an actual answer, wait the necessary amount of time before you can accept it as "the correct answer", and then mark it as such. Questions should stay questions.